# Can Mapside Join and Reduce side join have different O/P

Tags: hadoop, join, hive

The below code is present in PROD and runs daily, I am trying to optimize it.
I see that set hive.auto.convert.join=FALSE; is making it to do an Reduce side join which runs for 2.5 hours and produces an row count of 2324381 records.

If i set hive.auto.convert.join=TRUE; then it does an Map side join and runs only for 20 minutes and produces an row count of 5766529 records.

I need to know why the row counts differ and is this correct ? is it okay the row counts differ ? i was under the impression that the O/P or the query should remain the same irrespective of which join is happening.

The source data remains the same in both the case and every other condition is the same expect for the hive setting i am changing.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE krish
SELECT 
    s.svcrqst_id
    s.svcrqst_lupdusr_id,
    s.svcrqst_lstupd_dts as svcrqst_lupdt,
    f.crsr_lupdt,
    s.svcrqst_crt_dts,
    s.svcrqst_asrqst_ind,
    s.svcrtyp_cd,
    s.svrstyp_cd,
    s.asdplnsp_psuniq_id as psuniq_id,
    s.svcrqst_rtnorig_in,
    s.cmpltyp_cd,
    s.catsrsn_cd,
    s.apealvl_cd,
    s.cnstnty_cd,
    s.svcrqst_vwasof_dt,
    f.crsr_master_claim_index,
    t.svcrqct_cds,
    r.sum_reason_cd,
    r.sum_reason

from
table1 s
left outer join
(
    select distinct
    lpad(trim(i_srtp_sr_sbtyp_cd), 3, '0') as i_srtp_sr_sbtyp_cd,
    lpad(trim(i_srtp_sr_typ_cd), 3, '0') as i_srtp_sr_typ_cd,
    sum_reason_cd,
    sum_reason
    from table2 
) r
on lpad(trim(s.svcrtyp_cd), 3, '0')=r.i_srtp_sr_typ_cd
and lpad(trim(s.svrstyp_cd), 3, '0')=r.i_srtp_sr_sbtyp_cd

left outer join  table3 f
on trim(s.svcrqst_id)=trim(f.crsr_sr_id)

left outer join table4 t
on t.svcrqst_id=s.svcrqst_id

where
( year(s.svcrqst_lstupd_dts)=${hiveconf:YEAR} and month(s.svcrqst_lstupd_dts)=${hiveconf:MONTH} and day(s.svcrqst_lstupd_dts)=${hiveconf:DAY} )
or
( year(f.crsr_lupdt)=${hiveconf:YEAR} and month(f.crsr_lupdt)=${hiveconf:MONTH} and day(f.crsr_lupdt)=${hiveconf:DAY} )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research with my data, I created all my source tables with same column partitioned and bucketed and reran my HQL.

This time the number of rows for both map side join and reduce side join came with same counts.

I think on the previous query since the data was not partitioned the map side and reduce side joins have different output.